# clone: operation not permitted

Tags: linux, root, sudo

I am using [isolate](https://github.com/cms-dev/isolate), an isolator to isolate the execution of another program using Linux Containers. It's very handy and it works very well locally on my computer (I can run fork bombs and infinite loops and it protects everything).

Now I'm trying to get this to work on an Ubuntu 12.04 server I have, but I'm having some difficulties with it. It's a fresh server too.

When I run:

`sudo isolate --run -- mycommand`

(`mycommand` I usually try `python3` or something), I get:

`clone: Operation not permitted`

So, I dug up on the clone function (called like this in `isolate.c`):

```
box_pid = clone(
  box_inside,           // Function to execute as the body of the new process
  argv,         // Pass our stack
  SIGCHLD | CLONE_NEWIPC | CLONE_NEWNET | CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWPID,
  argv);            // Pass the arguments
if (box_pid < 0)
  die("clone: %m");
if (!box_pid)
  die("clone returned 0");
box_keeper();
```

Here's the Return Value of the function `clone`:

> On success, the thread ID of the child process is returned in the caller's thread of execution. On failure, -1 is returned in the caller's context, no child process will be created, and errno will be set appropriately.

And this is the error I'm getting:

> EPERM           Operation not permitted (POSIX.1)

And then I also found this:

> EPERM    CLONE_NEWNS was specified by a non-root process (process without CAP_SYS_ADMIN).

The `clone` function is indeed passing `CLONE_NEWNS` to run the program in a new namespace. I actually tried removing but I keep getting `clone: Operation not permitted`.

So, it all seems to point out to not having root privileges, but I actually ran the command as `root` (with and without `sudo` just to be sure), and also with a normal user in the sudoers group. None of that worked, but it works very well locally. Root privileges work for everything else but for some reason when I run this `isolate` program, it doesn't work.

I tried both with `isolate` in `/usr/bin` and running `./isolate` in a local folder too.

Comment: I don't know what isolate really does, but according to its source code, it drops root privileges - which seems rather relevant.

Comment: Yeah, it probably does, but locally it works even on a non-root account just using `sudo`.

Comment: What is the reason of going down to the such a low-level functions as `clone`? The guides that I have read all prohibit the usage of the one, the only exception is when you know what you're doing exactly...

Comment: I am pretty sure the people who wrote `isolate` are very aware of what they're doing.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue because I was trying to use isolate within a docker container.

Rerunning the container with the `--privileged` flag fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` to docker run.
Or also `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined`
Or also provide your own white list of allowed system calls, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/#pass-a-profile-for-a-container