# linux clone() returning -1 as child_pid

Tags: c, linux, docker

I have the following program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<sched.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

static char child_stack[2048];

static int child_fn() {
    printf("Pid: %ld\n", (long) getpid());
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    pid_t child_pid = clone(child_fn, child_stack+1024, CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWNS | SIGCHLD, NULL);
    printf("clone()= %ld\n", (long) child_pid);

    waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output

```
# ./clone                                                                                                       
clone()= -1
```

Can anyone help me understand why is it so?

> Note: I'm running this under a `docker` image with `ubuntu:latest`. Also notice that the prompt is `#` instead of `$`, so does it have anything to do with the user who's running this process, probably `root` in this case?

Comment: That means the [`clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) call *failed* and you need to check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see why. You *really* need to learn to read manual pages, as it's clearly written in them.

Comment: Unless you have a strong reason, I recommend to use the POSIX standard APIs, that is, `fork()` for processes and `pthread_create()` for threads. Using `clone()` where these standard functions would do is needlessly restricting your code to Linux.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry i missed that section on errno. I'm just getting started with this. I used strerror(3) to see the reason, I got `Operation not permitted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I used `strerror(3)` to find why I was getting the error. The error was `Operation not permitted`. I searched a bit about it and found the solution here - [clone: operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32126393/2972348)

So to fix it, all I had to do was to run my docker container with `--privileged` flag